# How to create method which will know that its instance is in matrix of another class

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm an absolute beginner in OOP (and C++). Trying to teach myself using resources my university offers for students of higher years, and a bunch of internet stuff I can find to clear things up.

I know basic things about OOP - I get the whole point of abstracting stuff into classes and using them to create objects, I know how inheritance works (at least, probably the basics), I know how to create operator functions (although as far as I can see that only helps in code readability in a sense that it becomes more standard, more language like), templates, and stuff like that.

So I've tried my first "project": to code Minesweeper (in command line, I never created a GUI before). Took me a few hours to create the program, and it works as desired, but I feel like I'm missing a huge point of OOP in there.

I've got a class "Field" with two attributes, a Boolean `mine` and a character `forShow`. I've defined the default constructor for it to initialize an instance as an empty field (`mine` is `false`), and `forShow`is `.` (indicating a not yet opened filed). I've got some simple inline functions such as `isMine`, `addMine`, `removeMine`, `setForShow`, `getForShow`, etc.

Then I've got the class `Minesweeper`. Its attributes are `numberOfColumns`, `~ofRows`, `numberOfMines`, a pointer `ptrGrid` of type `Mine*`, and `numberOfOpenedFields`. I've got some obvious methods such as `generateGrid`, `printGrid`, `printMines` (for testing purposes).

The main thingy about it is a function `openFiled` which writes the number of mines surrounding the opened field, and another function `clickField` which recursively calls itself for surrounding fields if the field which is currently being opened has `0` neighbor mines. **However**,  those two functions take an argument -- the index of the field in question. That kinda misses the point of OOP, if I understand it correctly.

For example, to call the function for the field right to the current one, I have to call it with argument `i+1`. The moment I noticed this, I wanted to make a function in my `Field` class which would return a pointer to the number right to it... but for the class `Field` itself, there is no matrix, so I can't do it!

Is it even possible to do it, is it too hard for my current knowledge? Or is there another more OOP-ish way to implement it?

**TLDR version:**

It's a noob's implemetation of Minesweeper game using C++. I got a class `Minesweeper` and `Field`. `Minesweeper` has a pointer to matrix of `Field`s, but the navigation through fields (going one up, down, wherever) doesn't seem OOP-ishly.

I want to do something like the following:

```
game->(ptrMatrix + i)->field.down().open(); // this
game->(ptrMatrix + i + game.numberOfColumns).open(); // instead of this

game->(ptrMatrix + i)->field.up().right().open(); // this
game->(ptrMatrix + i + 1 - game.numberOfColumns).open(); // instead of this
```

Comment: OOP is not the answer to everything. If it is not useful don't use it.

Comment: Seems trying to make things complex. OOP is a means to make things simple, not a purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you could do this in an OOP-ish manner. @Peter Schneider has provided one such way: have each cell know about its neighbours.

The real root of the problem is that you're using a dictionary (mapping exact coordinates to objects), when you want both dictionary-style lookups as well as neighbouring lookups. I personally wouldn't use "plain" OOP in this situation, I'd use templates.

```
/* Wrapper class. Instead of passing around (x,y) pairs everywhere as two
    separate arguments, make this into a single index. */
class Position {
private:
    int m_x, m_y;
public:
    Position(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}

    // Getters and setters -- what could possibly be more OOPy?
    int x() const { return m_x; }
    int y() const { return m_y; }
};

// Stubbed, but these are the objects that we're querying for.    
class Field {
public:
    // don't have to use an operator here, in fact you probably shouldn't . . .
    // ... I just did it because I felt like it. No justification here, move along.
    operator Position() const {
        // ... however you want to get the position
        // Probably want the Fields to "know" their own location.
        return Position(-1,-1);
    }
};

// This is another kind of query. For obvious reasons, we want to be able to query for
// fields by Position (the user clicked on some grid), but we also would like to look
// things up by relative position (is the cell to the lower left revealed/a mine?)
// This represents a Position with respect to a new origin (a Field).
class RelativePosition {
private:
    Field *m_to;
    int m_xd, m_yd;
public:
    RelativePosition(Field *to, int xd, int yd) : m_to(to), m_xd(xd),
        m_yd(yd) {}

    Field *to() const { return m_to; }

    int xd() const { return m_xd; }
    int yd() const { return m_yd; }
};

// The ultimate storage/owner of all Fields, that will be manipulated externally by
// querying its contents.
class Minefield {
private:
    Field **m_field;
public:
    Minefield(int w, int h) {
        m_field = new Field*[w];
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x ++) {
            m_field[w] = new Field[h];
        }
    }
    ~Minefield() {
        // cleanup
    }

    Field *get(int x, int y) const {
        // TODO: check bounds etc.
        // NOTE: equivalent to &m_field[x][y], but cleaner IMO.
        return m_field[x] + y;
    }
};

// The Query class! This is where the interesting stuff happens.
class Query {
public:
    // Generic function that will be instantiated in a bit.
    template<typename Param>
    static Field *lookup(const Minefield &field, const Param &param);
};

// This one's straightforwards . . .
template<>
Field *Query::lookup<Position>(const Minefield &field, const Position &pos) {
    return field.get(pos.x(), pos.y());
}

// This one, on the other hand, needs some precomputation.
template<>
Field *Query::lookup<RelativePosition>(const Minefield &field,
    const RelativePosition &pos) {

    Position base = *pos.to();
    return field.get(
        base.x() + pos.xd(),
        base.y() + pos.yd());
}

int main() {
    Minefield field(5,5);
    Field *f1 = Query::lookup(field, Position(1,1));
    Field *f0 = Query::lookup(field, RelativePosition(f1, -1, -1));

    return 0;
}
```

There are a couple of reasons why you might want to do it this way, even if it is complicated.

1. Decoupling the whole "get by position" idea from the "get neighbour" idea. As mentioned, these are fundamentally different, so expose a different interface.
2. Doing it in this manner gives you the opportunity to expand later with more Query types in a straightforwards fashion.
3. You get the advantage of being able to "store" a `Query` for later use. Perhaps to be executed in a different thread if it's a really expensive query, or in an event loop to be processed after other events, or . . . lots of reasons why you might want to do this.

You end up with something like this: (C++11 ahead, be warned!)

```
std::function<Field *()> f = std::bind(Query::lookup<RelativePosition>,
    field, RelativePosition(f1, -1, -1));
```

. . . wait, what?

Well, what we essentially want to do here is "delay" an execution of `Query::lookup(field, RelativePosition(f1, -1, -1))` for later. Or, rather, we want to "set up" such a call, but not actually execute it.

Let's start with `f`. What is `f`? Well, by staring at the type signature, it appears to be a function of some sort, with signature `Field *()`. How can a variable be a function? Well, it's actually more like a function *pointer*. (There are good reasons why not to call it a function pointer, but that's getting ahead of ourselves here.)

In fact, `f` can be assigned to *anything* that, when called, produces a `Field *` -- not just a function. If you overload the `operator ()` on a class, that's a perfectly valid thing for it to accept as well.

Why do we want to produce a `Field *` with no arguments? Well, that's an execution of the query, isn't it? But the function `Query::lookup<RelativePosition>` takes two arguments, right?

That's where `std::bind` comes in. `std::bind` essentially takes an `n`-argument function and turns it into an `m`-argument function, with `m <= n`. So the `std::bind` call takes in a two-place function (in this case), and then fixes its first two arguments, leaving us with . . .

. . . a zero-argument function, that returns a `Field *`.

And so we can pass around this "function pointer" to a different thread to be executed there, store it for later use, or even just repeatedly call it for kicks, and if the `Position` of `Field`s was to magically change for some reason (not applicable in this situation), the result of calling `f()` will dynamically update.

So now that I've turned a 2D array lookup into a mess of templates . . . we have to ask a question: is it worth it? I know this is a learning exercise and all, but my response: *sometimes, an array is really just an array*.

Answer (score 0):

You can link the four neighbours to the cell via pointers or references. That would likely happen after the playing field has been created. Whether that's good or bad design I'm not sure (I see the same charme though that you see). For large fields it would increase the memory footprint substantially, because a cell probably doesn't hold that much data besides these pointers:

```
class Cell
{
    // "real" data

    Cell *left, *right, *upper, *lower; 
    // and diagonals? Perhaps name them N, NE, E, SE, S...

};

void init()
{
    // allocate etc...

    // pseudo code
    foreach r: row 
    { 
        foreach c: column 
        { 
            // bounds check ok
            cells[r][c].upper = &cells[r-1][c];
            cells[r][c].left = &cells[r][c-1];
            // etc.
        }
    }

    // other stuff
}
```